# How do I implement GROUP BY in vaadin container using JPAContainer DefaultQueryModifierDelegate?

Tags: java, jpa, group-by, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin's JPAContainer to add where clauses, but how do I use group by?

```
data.getEntityProvider().setQueryModifierDelegate(
                new DefaultQueryModifierDelegate() {

                    @Override
                    public void filtersWillBeAdded(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery<?> query, List<Predicate> predicates) {

                        super.filtersWillBeAdded(criteriaBuilder, query, predicates);

                        //Where clauses

                        //query.groupBy(fromEntity.get(groupByColName)); ???

                    }
                }
```

I get an error

```
result returns more than one elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late...

I opened a Ticket
http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14484

and

pushed a patch 
https://dev.vaadin.com/review/#/c/4365/

Try it